# attaching onAnimationEnd for React-Leaflet CSS SVG route animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using the following to animate the route being drawn in React Leaflet, which works nicely. However I'd like to use `onAnimationEnd` for the CSS. I can't figure out where to find the element and attach the eventListener.

```js
export default function Map()
{
...
  const RoutingMachineRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    RoutingMachineRef.current.setWaypoints([start, end]);
  },[RoutingMachineRef, start, end]);
...
  return(
    <MapContainer>
      <RoutingMachine ref={RoutingMachineRef} waypoints={[start, end]} />
    </MapContainer>
  )
};
```

RoutingMachine.js

```js
const createRoutingMachineLayer = (props) =>
{
    const { waypoints } = props;
    const instance =  L.Routing.control(
    {
        waypoints,
        // router: router,
        lineOptions: {
            styles: [ {className:'animate'} ]
        },
        show: false,
        addWaypoints: false,
        routeWhileDragging: false,
        draggableWaypoints: false,
        fitSelectedRoutes: true,
        showAlternatives: false,
        createMarker: function() { return null; },
    })
    return instance
}

const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(createRoutingMachineLayer)    
export default RoutingMachine;
```

CSS:

```css
path.leaflet-interactive.animate {
    stroke-dasharray: 1920;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1920;
    animation: dash 20s linear 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `path.leaflet-interactive.animate` is properly animating as you expect, isn't that the element you need to listen to for `animationend`?

Comment: yes! but in react I can't seem to attach an eventListener to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set this up very nicely.   Your `RoutingMachine` component is well written, and you already have your ref to it.  Great.  Let's examine `RoutingMachineRef` in the console:

[image]

As you can see, if you dig through, the svg path component can be found at `RoutingMachineRef.current._line._layers[some_layer_id]._path`.  But *watch out* because sometimes leaflet routing machine will draw multiple layers (separate svg layers for rounded line caps, etc).  You can actually access these dom elements directly through the RoutingMachineRef.

I'm not sure which one of these gets the `.animate` css class in your code, but you can probably just add your event listener to each of these.  I imagine only one of them is going to actually animate (potentially a problematic assumption there), so the event listener will only fire once, when the one that has the `.animate` class stops animating:

```js
const RoutingMachineRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    RoutingMachineRef.current.setWaypoints([start, end]);
    const pathComponents = Object.values(RoutingMachineRef.current._line._layers);
    pathComponents.forEach((component) => {
      component._path.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
        // animateend callback code here
      });
    });
  },[RoutingMachineRef, start, end]);
```

I created a codesandbox to help demonstrate.  I don't have any actual animations going on, so I just added a click listener.  When the page loads and the route shows up, click on it, and you can see it is listening to the click event.

### [Sample Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlv3-routing-machine-animate-q16cj)

I wrote my codesandbox a little different than our code, as it seems you have some state variables `start` and `end` that trigger the useEffect to run.  For my case, I have no such state vars to help trigger the useEffect - I want it to run on mount. But *watch out* because you can't expect your useEffect to be able to propertly utilize a ref variable on mount, as refs are not created under after the first render.  But on the other hand, trying to trigger useEffects by sticking a ref in the dep array is rife with problems.  So I added a listener on the routingMachine leaflet instance's event `routesfound`, which sets the state variable `routerReady` to true, and then I include *that* in the dep array.  The logic here is that once the routing machine is created, and it completes its first search, I trigger a useEffect to add these event listeners.  You will likely need to tweak this logic to suit your needs - if your waypoints are dynamic, you will need to add listeners every time a new route is drawn, as its an entirely new svg path that gets drawn.

Comment: Amazing - thank you Seth, I spent a while yesterday examining the Ref in the console using `console.dir()` and was at a loss as to how to proceed. This is incredibly useful for learning the process, not just the answer. I'll check it out shortly - cheers!

Comment: okay seth - using your method here I still can't get anything to fire at the end of the animation - and the object shows `null` for `onanimationend: null` when using `onanimationend` and `animationend` as the arg for the event listener

Comment: interestingly - i can now get this in the console using codepen: `Error occurred while trying to quickly transform '/node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js' ` I don't get any kind of error reported in the console in my dev environment on chrome ::

here's my fork of your codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/rlv3-routing-machine-animate-forked-2vtu7

Comment: This works, but it `instance.on()` never fires again.

Comment: You were super close.  The issue is that the useEffect which attaches the listener was only being fired when `routerReady` changed.  You need it to fire *also* any time the waypoints changed.  So you need to add `wayPoints` to that dep array, and also use `setWayPoints` in the same place you use `routerRef.current.setWaypoints` [this csb works on every route change](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlv3-routing-machine-animate-forked-2md6z) (check the console).  As far as the delay at the end, that may have more to do with CSS and some delay between the scg animating, and actually firing the event